# How to fix JMeter ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: jmeter

I'm testing `http://lifecharger.org/make-the-rest-of-your-life-the-best-of-your-life/` through Jmeter and I'm getting below error.

my JMeter version is `5.1.1`

```java
2019-07-08 11:47:04,668 ERROR o.a.j.g.a.ActionRouter: Error processing org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Start@12ab28e
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Start.startEngine(Start.java:188) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Start.doAction(Start.java:114) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:88) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:70) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
```

How to fix this issue?

I'm using [jmeter automation testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8loLHbhfyh0&list=PLhW3qG5bs-L-zox1h3eIL7CZh5zJmci4c&index=2) resource to learn JMeter

[image: error image]

Comment: just learning sample request!

Comment: Please check out the question, I just updated!

Comment: I created a Thread group, you can see a small gear icon in the screen shot

Answer (score 17):

Your Test Plan is disabled (gray) and that's causing the exception

You can enable it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> or Right Click on it and Enable

Comment: shame that GUI does not report this

Comment: @PetrKozelka I agree, consider to open a bug in https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=JMeter